# Is BCE commutative?

Tags: binary-crossentropy

Is binary cross entropy commutative? Both in math theory and in PyTorch?

I'm not fresh enough on my math to tell straight by looking at the formula and code.

`BCE(x,y) =?= BCE(y,x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary cross-entropy is *not* commutative, and the two elements typically used with it in machine learning - ground truth $y$ and estimate of class probability $\hat{y}$ - are not interchangeable conceptually either.

The BCE loss function is:

$$\mathcal{L}(y,\hat{y}) = -y\text{log}(\hat{y}) - (1-y)\text{log}(1-\hat{y})$$

Ground truth $y$ is commonly either $0$ or $1$ for data records where an individual example is either a class member or not. If that value was used in place of $\hat{y}$ then one of logs would be $\text{log}(0)$ which is undefined.

You can generate example outputs when both $y$ and $\hat{y}$ are between $0$ and $1$, and see that the loss function is not symmetric:

- $\mathcal{L}(0.5,0.9) \approx 1.204$
- $\mathcal{L}(0.9,0.5) \approx 0.693$

Comment: We can also generate the graphic. The contour shows the asymmetry better than the 3D plot. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%3Dx*log%28y%29%2B%281-x%29log%281-y%29